# Instagram black screens on launch - Samsung S22

Tags: instagram

I have recently reset my instagram password and logged out of my account on my phone. However, I am now unable to use Instagram on my phone as it just black screens.

I am able to log into my account online(computer).

I have tried uninstalling, clearing the cache and restarting my phone to no avail.
I have also tried installing a prior version of Instagram, which did nothing to my situation.